# How to avoid build errors with aspx include files?

Tags: asp.net, include

I have an aspx file that will contain a lot of sections and I would prefer to have each section in its own include file. I'm okay to put all of the code behind into the main file. I'm using: <!-- #include file ="section1.aspx" --> in the body. When I build (I'm still only including the first section with code), I get "The name 'lbl_phone' does not exist in the current context" because the code behind has a routine that references this screen field which IS in the include file. What is a better way to go about this?

Edit (as it is now, hope I cut it down properly here, builds good now but error in browser):

file ola.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="_ola" Codebehind="ola.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="section" TagName="account" Src="account.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><body><form id="ola_form1" runat="server">
<section:account id="section_account" runat="server" />
</form></body></html>
```

file: ola.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
    public partial class _ola : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_phone.Text = "000-000-1234";
    }
}
```

file: account.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="_ola" CodeBehind="account.ascx.cs" %>
Call us at <asp:Label ID="lbl_phone" runat="server" Text="lbl_phone"></asp:Label>
```

At runtime in the browser, I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (for the line with lbl_phone.Text = ...)

Comment: I ended up putting code behind for each section that is only relevant to each section using the following at the top of the .ascx files:  <%@ Control Language="C#" CodeFile="section1.ascx.cs" Inherits="_section1" %>

Answer (score 1):

Don't use server side includes. They don't work well in the ASP.NET architecture.

Instead, embed reusable stuff into .ASCX user controls. [MSDN How To article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

ASCX File MyControl.ascx

```
<% @ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Spinner" %>  
<table>
<tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>Some content</td><td>Some more content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then this can be embedded on as many ASPX pages as you like.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyControlName" Src="~\Controls\MyControl.ascx" %>
<uc:MyControlName ID="MyControl1" runat="server" />
```

Edit- You should make these ASCX files as portable as possible in your application so that they're self contained units. There shouldn't be much of a need for your ASPX code behind to reference a control contained in the ASCX file. You can do code behinds for user controls (MyControl.ascx.cs or MyControl.ascx.vb) if necessary, or you can use a script block to embed the code directly in the ASCX page.

.NET Framework will not follow server side includes and so it won't compile properly if you try to reference a control that is being included via SSI. But you could potentially reference a control in an ASCX file. For example...

MyAdvancedControl.ascx

```
<% @ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Spinner" %>  
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl_phone" />
<script runat="server">
public Label Lbl_phone {get {return lbl_phone;}}
</script>
```

MyPage.aspx

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyAdvancedControlName" Src="~\Controls\MyAdvancedControl.ascx" %>
<uc:MyAdvancedControlName ID="MyControl2" runat="server" />
```

MyPage.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyControl2.Lbl_phone.Text="Galaxy S4";
}
```

Comment: Your sample does not match what I am doing. Your sample has c# code. I want to include aspx (html) code to the .aspx file. All of the c# coding will be in the single code behind. ??

Comment: @HankKnah My example has a script and embedded controls (TextBox and two Buttons). You can put regular HTML elements in there too.

Comment: @HankKnah I modified it to more closely match what you've described.

Comment: Are you saying every include file should be .ascx? Does the %@ Register line go where I want to include the code in the main aspx file or at the top (then how to get it to display in place)?  How do tagprefix and tagname work with each other? I couldn't grasp the user control thing when I read up on it.

Comment: An ASCX is a way of encapsulating a set of controls (and logic that goes with those controls) onto a reusable control that can be placed on any page in your site. The Register directive goes at the top of your page below the Page directive (you can also register controls in your web.config file to avoid having to individually register on each page). Tag prefix and tag name are used to provide a namespace for referring to your controls. Look at the tutorials for ASCX user controls and Master Pages.

Comment: main.aspx has &lt;%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyControlName" Src="account.ascx" %&gt; and in the body is &lt;uc:MyControlName ID="MyControl1" runat="server" /&gt; and in account.ascx is &lt;%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="account.ascx.cs" ClassName="account" %&gt; plus html/aspx code. When I build, i get the following two errors: Identifier expected (in account.ascx.designer.cs "public partial class  {" and a warning for the &lt;uc:MyControlName of "Element 'MyControlName' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the We..."

Comment: Got rid of the build errors but when I view in Browser I get an error:  Parser Error Message: '_ola' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.  
Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="account.ascx.cs" Inherits="_ola" ClassName="_ola" %>

Comment: @HankKnah Edit your question so it clearly shows your code and your problem. Comments aren't a good place for that.

Comment: I appended the initial question with code. Thank you for your help this far!

Comment: Is there another parameter somewhere that it needs?

Answer (score 0):

Controls defined as part of a Page or Master Page or User Control are private by default. To get around that, add a public property that exposes it. Put this property in account.ascx.cs

```
public Label lbl_phone_public_version{ 
    get {
        return lbl_phone;
    } 
}
```

When you try to reference lbl_phone from code on ola.aspxcs, you have to do it through the parent control, like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    section_account.lbl_phone_public_version.Text = "000-000-1234";
}
```

Comment: Okay, much thanks! Would you also have a sample of how to go the other direction too? Say the phone number is in a dataset from sql in the main .aspx that I want to use one in the ascx.cs file. If it was in the aspx.cs it would be lbl_phone.Text = compDetails.Rows[0]["PhoneNumb"].ToString(); but how to set that up to set it in the ascx.cs?

Comment: @HankKnah You could pass in the ID of the control that is on the Page, then have the user control go find that control. It gets messy though. It's best to design user controls so they are portable.